Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'. 2 files found with path 'xxx' from inputs
when I try to upgrade the gradle of project from 4.2.2 to 7.5, it come out this error:
2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libflush.so' from inputs:
 - /home/chen/smu-dev/CacheTemplateAttackForJNI/ccattack/app/build/intermediates/merged_jni_libs/debug/out/arm64-v8a/libflush.so
 - /home/chen/smu-dev/CacheTemplateAttackForJNI/ccattack/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/4y3k95n3/obj/arm64-v8a/libflush.so
If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets


my build.gradle is something like that:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "e.smu.ccattack"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        ndk{
            //abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            // abiFilters "arm64-v8a","armeabi-v7a"
             abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {

        main {
            // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/cpp/libflush/libs/']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}


my cmakelists.txt is like:
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

#/home/finder/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
#set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -fpermissive")

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib
        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED
        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp
        )

# OatParser
add_library(
        liboatparser
        #code for parser
        SHARED
        #oatparser
        oat-parser/base/bit_vector-inl.h
        oat-parser/oat/instruction_set.h
        oat-parser/elf/elfloader.cpp
        oat-parser/elf/map_file.h
        oat-parser/zlib/adler32.c
        oat-parser/oat/DexHeader.h
        oat-parser/oat/OATHeader.cpp
        oat-parser/art/compiler_filter.cpp
        oat-parser/oat/OATParser.cpp
        oat-parser/logoutput.h
        oat-parser/StringPiece.cpp
)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib
        log)

#add_library(libflush SHARED IMPORTED)
#set_target_properties(libflush
#        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
#        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libflush/libs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}/libflush.so)
set(libflush ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libflush/libs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}/libflush.so)
#include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libflush/libflush/)
# add_subdirectory(DEX)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib
        ${libflush}
        liboatparser
        #${LIB_LIEF}
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib}) #NDK

target_link_libraries(
        liboatparser
        ${log-lib}
)

I really need some help, if you want more information, please do let me know.
Thanks!!
I try to compile this project, and I try to delete the file, but it will regenerate once again.
